# ASP.NET Web Forms Server.Transfer With Async

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, async-await

I'm trying to use async, task await to speed up the execution of a page. According to all my reading everyone has suggest using the Page.RegisterAsyncTask method.

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure base functionality is called for menu logic
    base.Page_Load(sender, e);

    if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Register and execute async tasks
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(BindDropdownsAsync));
        Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();

        this.SetupPage();
    }
}
```

The asynchronous method that is registered is below.

```
private async Task BindDropdownsAsync()
{
    Task<EmployerResponseWrapper<IList<EmployerSectorModel>>> employerSectorModelTask = this.EmployerService.GetSectorAsync();
    Task<EmployerResponseWrapper<IList<ProvinceModel>>>  Task<List<ProvinceModel>> getProvinceAsyncTask = this.EmployerService.GetProvinceAsync();
    Task<EmployerResponseWrapper<IList<EmployerStatusModel>>> Task<List<EmployerStatusModel>> getEmployerStatusTask = this.EmployerService.GetStatusAsync();
    Task<EmployerResponseWrapper<IList<PrivatePayrollModel>>> Task<List<PrivatePayrollModel>> getPrivatePayrollTask = this.EmployerService.GetPrivatePayrollAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(employerSectorModelTask, getProvinceAsyncTask, getEmployerStatusTask, getPrivatePayrollTask);

    this.rcbSector.DataSource = employerSectorModelTask.Result.Data;
    this.rcbProvince.DataSource = getProvinceAsyncTask.Result.Data;
    this.rcbStatus.DataSource = getEmployerStatusTask.Result.Data;
    this.rcbPrivatePayRoll.DataSource = getPrivatePayrollTask.Result.Data;

    this.rcbSector.DataBind();
    this.rcbProvince.DataBind();
    this.rcbStatus.DataBind();
    this.rcbPrivatePayRoll.DataBind();
}
```

The asynchronous method is working fine when i go directly to the page. However this page is access from a search screen where you are transferred to the screen using `Server.Transfer` I get the following error.

```
 System.Web.HttpException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Error executing child request for /GB/Marketing/Employer/EmployerCreateUpdate.aspx.
  Source=GB.Web
  StackTrace:
   at GB.Web.Marketing.Employer.EmployerSearch.rgEmployerSearch_ItemCommand(Object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) in C:\Information Systems\Web Applications\Greenbox\development\v13.9 - Employer Overhaul\Web\Site\Marketing\Employer\EmployerSearch.aspx.cs:line 71
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.OnItemCommand(GridCommandEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.
```

It appears that it's waiting for my code to execute so it can't transfer to the page.

So can i not use Server.Transfer with async await Task ?

Comment: I know this is not the comment you'd like to get, but I'd avoid using Server.Transfer. Why wouldn't you use Response.Redirect?

Comment: Why would you avoid using Server.Transfer ? I'm using it since i have values stored in the ViewState and Session which the page i'm transferring too needs to know about.

If i use response.redirect i would have to put these variables in a query string which makes the URL look ugly. Additionally i then have to on the page load of each of the pages read and store the values into the viewstate.

Comment: IMHO. Server.Transfer sounds legacy to me, it comes from ASP 3.0. I don't see solutions these days using Server.Transfer.

Comment: Well, Server.Transfer is useful since it only does 1 round trip to the server and is functionally different from Response.Redirect. 

The other difference being that Server.Transfer is a request from the server to transfer to the new page while Response.Redirect is the browser issuing the command to go to the new page.

I can look at using response.redirect but my question still stands why isn't it working with Server.Transfer :(